# Plotting a simple function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the function

```
f:[-10,10] -> R
f(x) = 2*x+8, x<=2
f(x) = 3*x*x, x>2
```

My code:

```
    function [] = func3()
    X = linspace(-10,10,100);
        if (X<=2)
            Y=2.*X+8;
            plot(X,Y);
        else
            Y=3.*X.*X;
            plot(X,Y);
        end
end
```

It show a graph for the function but it's not the correct one. I can't understand why is that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [`if`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) branch is only entered if its vector argument contains *all* entries different than zero. So in your case it's never entered, and only the `else` part is executed. That part uses *all* values of vector `X`, to which it applies the quadratic function.

To do what you want, replace the `if` by [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
X = linspace(-10,10,100);
ind = X<=2;
Y(ind) = 2*X(ind)+8; %// apply affine part of function only to these values of X
Y(~ind) = 3*X(~ind).^2; %// apply quadratic part of function to the remaining values
plot(X,Y);
```